# Is there any way to send the webpages as demo for testing? like .ipa files in ios

Tags: php, web, demo

Am developing website using php, is there any way to  send the demo of the pages to colleague for testing.

Am asking because in ios we can send .ipa package as like android also possible.What about this web development.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: As the pages are generated "on request", it's difficult. You can use your browser to "save file" and send them that, but all they can do is look at it; or you set up a test server that they have access to, which is what (I suspect) most developers do

Comment: I think he wants something that will Pack and unpack the files. The same way ipa does.

Comment: @Aizen ya you r right.

Answer (score 0):

A solution would be to use a codeanywhere.com DevBox. It's a test server on the internet with a ready-to-use editor.

You could first test the project yourself, tweak it to instantly work of a codeanywhere DevBox and just tell him to register there, upload the files and test it on the fly :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try [vagrant](https://www.vagrantup.com/)，It will help your colleague build the same runtime environment automatically !

Comment: my collegue have not knowledge about php.can he work with this